# Changing cookie JSESSIONID name

Tags: java, tomcat, jsessionid

I have a requirement of having to run multiple tomcat server in single physical box. While accessing these from a browser, when user switches between the applications, it results in logging out the user previously access application. This is because of JSESSIONID cookie conflict.

One possible solution is to run each applications in different context. Unfortunately, my applications will not work in context path setting as none of the resources are accessed with request.getContextPath() prepended in front.

This leaves me to change the name of cookie JSESSIONID to resolve the conflict. Is there a way to do this? If yes, how?

Hope I'm clear in stating my question.

Note: All my application are running in different port in the same machine.

Comment: How are you managing to run "multiple tomcat server" on the same ports as each other at the same time?

Comment: @HarryLime: Can happen with a proxy server.

Answer (score 66):

Everything is much simpler with Servlet API 3.0.

Now you can configure it in your web.xml:

```
<session-config>
    <cookie-config>
        <name>MY_JSESSIONID_YAHOOOOOO</name>
    </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

That's it!

Comment: the best answer!

Comment: I did use this configuration but, seems like it is not working all the time, because of that I asked my question here and got some other suggestion.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54698948/renaming-jsessionid

Comment: Does anyone have a solution to this in a Spring boot application? Would be a great help

Comment: @JawadhSalihRifath in your application properties 
server.servlet.session.cookie.name=

Answer (score 18):

The following works for me on Tomcat7 in the context.xml file:

```
<Context path="/yourApp" sessionCookieName="custom_session_id">
```

Answer (score 14):

By Using two following system properties this can be achieved with ease.

- org.apache.catalina.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME
- org.apache.catalina.SESSION_PARAMETER_NAME

Any value can be passed to above properties to change the default values.

Here [complete details](http://www.digizol.com/2010/10/jsessionid-tomcat-cookie-change-default.html) with some sample script is found.

Comment: This does not work anymore for Tomcat7+. Now you can set it in the Context configuration, see @timkingman's answer.

Comment: I did this on tomcat 6 , but still I am getting the same problem

Answer (score 12):

Tomcat 7 moves this from org.apache.catalina.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME to an attribute on the main <Context> config.
http://tomcat.apache.org/migration-7.html#Session_manager_configuration

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's possible at this point - see https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=42419

The last entry states "This has been fixed in 5.5.x and will be included in 5.5.28 onwards" - which is the next point release - 5.5.27 is the current release.

Comment: Thanks for digging this out. Looks like only option left for me is to modify the existing tomcat source. 
The bug/feature report clearly states my exact requirement and solution.
Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% sure if this will work, but you can use the `jvmRoute` attribute, which is generally used in a load-balanced/clustered environment for the load balancers to be able to tell the nodes apart. Example:

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="node1">
```

This will end up generating a JSESSIONID value that looks like "ABCDEF123456.node1".

[Documentation link](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/engine.html).

Comment: This about the value of the cookie, not its name, right?

Answer (score 0):

I found it in Tomcat at /tomcat/conf/server.xml

server.xml

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="instanceName">
```

5D33F755D8D75EF7C8E840.instanceName

Answer (score 0):

```
    final SessionCookieConfig sessionCookieConfig = servletContext.getSessionCookieConfig();
    sessionCookieConfig.setSecure(true);
    sessionCookieConfig.setHttpOnly(true);
    // Set __Host- prefix
    sessionCookieConfig.setName("__Host-JSESSIONID");
```