# GWT & XSRF Protection

Tags: gwt, rpc, csrf, owasp

I'm looking at possible solutions to protect my GWT app against XSRF.

If I understand [GWT's solution](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideSecurityRpcXsrf.html) correctly - it makes available a Servlet which you use to both generate the token on the client-side (when calling your RPC endpoint) and to validate on the server-side (when the call hits your service).

Does this solution only cater for RPC calls? Surely we need it to cover all user generated requests to the server?

Any other recommended XSRF solutions (I'm also looking at [OWASP's CSRFGuard](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_CSRFGuard_Project))?

Comment: What types of user generated requests are you using besides GWT RPC?

Comment: We have some servlets, a Jack Rabbit repository etc which the user can generate requests for.

Answer (score 5):

I modified the GWT Sample App to be protected against XSRF.  This solution is roughly based of the solution provided in the GWT developer docs.  http://code.google.com/p/xsrf-safe/

Comment: I looked at your solution, what I am wandering, where do you create and handle the cookie on the client side? Because i do not use google-apps, how can I use the cookie JSESSIONID, which does not have a value, where do you set the value of the cookie, and how do you handle the cookie... can you explain this, or point me to a link? tnx

Comment: "JSESSIONID cookie is created/sent when session is created. Session is created when your code calls request.getSession() or request.getSession(true) for the first time." -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595872/under-what-conditions-is-a-jsessionid-created

Comment: In the example request.getSession() is called in Xsrf_Safe.jsp http://code.google.com/p/xsrf-safe/source/browse/trunk/war/Xsrf_Safe.jsp

Comment: So you are acctually giving the session value as an javascript variable,"xsrf" : %=XsrfTokenUtil.getToken(request.getSession().getId())%>" but where do you call Cookie.create()... how come you have already generated cooke.. does this follows using google-apps-engine and the sessions enabled? Because my code requires to expicitly create the cookie with the given name

Comment: The JSESSIONID cookie is created automatically by the server when using sessions. It is not App Engine specific, it's part of JSP.  The GWT client doesn't use cookies directly, the cookies just maintains the session.  The JSP uses the session id to generate a secure token, and injects the token as a javascript variable.  The client just reads the javascript variable and passes it back in the HTTP header in each GWT-RPC request.  The server then validates the token from the header. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: If you just need to rename the JSESSIONID cookie, there are some options depending on which server you use.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/877064/changing-cookie-jsessionid-name

Comment: What's the purpose of hashing the session ID?