# Spring boot configure custom jsessionid for embedded server

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsessionid

I want to configure my servlet context, such as setting a custom jsessionId key (see [Changing cookie JSESSIONID name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877064/changing-cookie-jsessionid-name))

I believe I can use the `SpringBootServletInitializer` when running a WAR file, manipulating the `servletContext` in `onStartup()`. However, when I run on an embedded application server, using
`new SpringApplicationBuilder().run()`, I don't know the best place to manipulate the servlet context.

Comment: I'm quite suspicious of your motives. If you change the cookie name you won't be able to take advantage of common load-balancing algorithms for instance. I can't really understand why it's necessary.

Comment: @DaveSyer I'm curious, How come it will affect LB algorithm? We are planning to change the cookie name to hide the tech stack details from attackers.

Comment: Sticky session load balancing usually relies on a cookie name, for instance.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

As of **Spring Boot 1.3** you can simply set a configuration property;

**Spring Boot 1.3, 1.4, 1.5**

```
server.session.cookie.name = MYSESSIONID
```

**Spring Boot 2.x**

```
server.servlet.session.cookie.name = MYSESSIONID
```

A lot simpler than writing a configuration class.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html for more session related properties.

Comment: This is deprecated, the new configuration name is `server.servlet.session.cookie.name`

Answer (score 28):

Declare a `ServletContextInitializer` bean in your application's configuration:

```java
@Bean
public ServletContextInitializer servletContextInitializer() {
    return new ServletContextInitializer() {

        @Override
        public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
            servletContext.getSessionCookieConfig().setName("yourCookieName");
        }
    };

}
```

Alternatively, your application class itself can implement `ServletContextInitializer`:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application implements ServletContextInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        servletContext.getSessionCookieConfig().setName("yourCookieName");
    }

}
```

Comment: Great job Mr.Wilkinson have been searching this for some time now! Keep up the good work.

Comment: Wildfly users: This was the only solution that worked for setting the JSESSIONID path (setting the server.servlet.session.cookie.path did NOT).

Comment: Second note for Wildfly users.  I had to add super.onStartup(servletContext); to the beginning of the onStartup method, otherwise my CORS configuration/headers got blown away.  Tomcat didn't seem to need this.

Comment: @java-addict301, you can't call `super.onStartup(servletContext)` in this case. The superclass of both the anonymous inner-class (my first example) and `Application` (my second example) is `Object` and it has no `onStartup(ServletContext)` method so attempting to call `super.onStartup(servletContext)` won't compile. Perhaps your `ServletContextInitializer` has a different superclass?

Comment: Ah yes you're right, I'm overriding this in my main @SpringBootApplication class (which extends SpringBootServletInitializer).  I'm on Spring Boot version 2.1.1

Answer (score 4):

with spring session , if you want to change cookie name ,you can do this

```
@Bean
public DefaultCookieSerializer defaultCookieSerializer(){
    DefaultCookieSerializer defaultCookieSerializer = new DefaultCookieSerializer();
    defaultCookieSerializer.setCookieName("mySessionId");
    return defaultCookieSerializer;
}
```

i find this in spring session source

spring-session-1.2.1.RELEASE-sources.jar!/org/springframework/session/config/annotation/web/http/SpringHttpSessionConfiguration.java

```
    @Autowired(required = false)
public void setCookieSerializer(CookieSerializer cookieSerializer) {
    this.defaultHttpSessionStrategy.setCookieSerializer(cookieSerializer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER).and()
    .csrf().disable();  
}
```

You can try this as it removes jsession id from URL

Comment: Kill a patient if he has a disease. Nice answer

Comment: @iamareebjamal hahahha! made my day :D