# Custom SessionID for HttpSession in Spring

Tags: spring, session, httpsession

I would like to know if it is possible to tell the Session which ID it should carry. Googleling around made me feel like it is not. Is that true?

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25918556/spring-boot-configure-custom-jsessionid-for-embedded-server

Comment: Does that allow me to change the value itself?
It looks like it is just setting the key-name under which the sessionID itself is stored. Please tell me if I am wrong.

Comment: why do you need to change actual id?

Comment: We would like to replace the id with an id generated by the database (that one looks a bit like a guid). We would then use this ID for both spring security and db stuff.