# Change session cookie name and path in Spring Boot WebFlux

Tags: spring, spring-boot, session-cookies, spring-webflux, reactive

I'm creating a reactive Spring Boot project using WebFlux. I need to configure the session cookie name and path.

In a Tomcat based project it is very easy to [configure the session cookie using the configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34334070) file:

```
server.servlet.session.cookie.name = MYSESSIONID
server.servlet.session.cookie.path = /
```

If I configure these properties in the WebFlux project it doesn't affect the cookie parameters. How to do that?

Comment: as you can see in the property it says "servlet" webflux does not use servlets.

Comment: That's right, this is exactly why I'm asking. What is the equivalent configuration in WebFlux.

Comment: there is none, webflux uses netty, you have to lookup how to do it in netty, i can't answer that

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be using Spring Session you can create your own bean for the `WebSessionIdResolver` which is what sets the name (and other attributes) of the session cookie.

```
@Configuration
public class CookieConfig {

    @Bean
    public WebSessionIdResolver webSessionIdResolver() {
        CookieWebSessionIdResolver resolver = new CookieWebSessionIdResolver();
        resolver.setCookieName("MYSESSIONID");
        return resolver;
    }

}
```

The Spring Session guides cover this in [Spring Session - WebFlux with Custom Cookie](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/2.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html5/guides/boot-webflux-custom-cookie.html).

Comment: I also needed to add @EnableSpringWebSession and a ReactiveSessionRepository bean