# Renaming JSESSIONID

Tags: spring, jsessionid

I tried to rename JSESSIONID as below in web.xml, but seems like sometimes I do see the default name in the logs(I am logging in a filter in case default name is given), any idea?, 
I am using spring 3.2.18 and servlet-api-3.1

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>45</session-timeout>
    <cookie-config>
      <path>/</path>
      <domain>.example.com</domain>
      <name>XXX_JSESSIONID</name>
    </cookie-config>
  </session-config>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are using `spring-3.2.18` you should try the following code to override `DefaultCookieSerializer`. You can find detail information in [Spring Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/java-custom-cookie.html)

```
@Bean
public DefaultCookieSerializer defaultCookieSerializer(){
    DefaultCookieSerializer defaultCookieSerializer = new DefaultCookieSerializer();
    defaultCookieSerializer.setCookieName("mySessionId");
    return defaultCookieSerializer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without clear logs about what is happening, it could be the client browser that send back cookies stored with the default name 'JSESSIONID'.

In that you should first delete JSESSIONID cookie from the client browser (expire)